# How can I change React Native iOS simulator DarkMode?

Tags: react-native

I wrote code and did shift + command + a in iOS simulator but I could see mode is not changed from `console.log` what is the problem?

```html
    
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native-web";
import Movies from "../screens/Movies";
import Search from "../screens/Search";
import Tv from "../screens/Tv";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const Tabs = () => {
    const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
    console.log(colorScheme);
    
    return(
        <Tab.Navigator >
            <Tab.Screen name="Movies" component={Movies} options={{
            }}/>
            <Tab.Screen name="Tv" component={Tv}/>
            <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={Search}/>
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}
export default Tabs;
```

Answer (score 1):

first :

```js
import * as RN from "react-native";
import {
  DarkTheme,
  DefaultTheme,
  NavigationContainer,
} from "@react-navigation/native";
```

in App.js :

```js
let cs = RN.useColorScheme();
let isDark = cs === "dark";
let theme = isDark ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme; // or your custom theme [1]
...
```

```js
...
<NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
 <Tabs />
</NavigationContainer>
...
```

[1] : [react-navigation theme](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/themes)

and if you want use react-navigation theme object in functional components :

```js
import { useTheme } from "@react-navigation/native";
```

and after defining your function component :

```js
let { colors, dark } = useTheme();
```

and in JSX :

```js
...
<View
 style={{
 width: 100,
 height: 175,
 margin: 10,
 alignItems: "center",
 borderWidth: 1,
 backgroundColor: colors.primary,
 borderRadius: 10,
 justifyContent: "space-evenly",
 }}
/>
...
```

Comment: thanks a lot!  i will try this but I know that it is toggled light/dark when using a shortcut key(shift + command + a) in the simulator, but it is fixed in light mode ...

Comment: i solved... i imported react-native-web

Comment: If you've careful I called the useColorScheme hook via the RN.useColorSheme command

Comment: The idea is right but that code could do with refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

The `getColorScheme()` hook will always return light when debugging with Chrome. Disable debugging to return `dark`.

Example to debug

```
const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (colorScheme) {
      Alert.alert(colorScheme)
    }
  }, [colorScheme])
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, where my code was exactly as the handbook around switching to whatever the user set.

However the `shift + command + a` command did nothing.
Turns out this happens if you still have `userInterfaceStyle` set to `light` hardcoded in `app.json` file of react-native.

(Somehow completely missed that step)

So to fix it, set `app.json` to include:

```js
"userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
```

Hope it helps others looking for the same answer.